# opencv dnn module with OpenVino

Tags: c++, opencv, openvino

I have no problems when working with dnn module
But I have downloaded OPENVINO to use dnn with engine inference, and I can't load the opencv_dnn452d.dll library
When I go to the opencv subdirecotry in openvino, and execute opencv_version_win32d.exe, I get this output, that says that inference engine has 3 backends (ONETBB, TBB and OPENM) , but none of them can be checked correctly:

```
[ INFO:0] global C:\jenkins\workspace\OpenCV\OpenVINO\2021.3\build\windows\opencv\modules\core\src\parallel\registry_parallel.impl.hpp (90) cv::parallel::ParallelBackendRegistry::ParallelBackendRegistry core(parallel): Enabled backends(3, sorted by priority): ONETBB(1000); TBB(990); OPENMP(980)
[ INFO:0] global C:\jenkins\workspace\OpenCV\OpenVINO\2021.3\build\windows\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\openvino_2021.3.394\opencv\bin\opencv_core_parallel_onetbb452_64d.dll => FAILED
[ INFO:0] global C:\jenkins\workspace\OpenCV\OpenVINO\2021.3\build\windows\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load opencv_core_parallel_onetbb452_64d.dll => FAILED
[ INFO:0] global C:\jenkins\workspace\OpenCV\OpenVINO\2021.3\build\windows\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\openvino_2021.3.394\opencv\bin\opencv_core_parallel_tbb452_64d.dll => FAILED
[ INFO:0] global C:\jenkins\workspace\OpenCV\OpenVINO\2021.3\build\windows\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load opencv_core_parallel_tbb452_64d.dll => FAILED
[ INFO:0] global C:\jenkins\workspace\OpenCV\OpenVINO\2021.3\build\windows\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\openvino_2021.3.394\opencv\bin\opencv_core_parallel_openmp452_64d.dll => FAILED
[ INFO:0] global C:\jenkins\workspace\OpenCV\OpenVINO\2021.3\build\windows\opencv\modules\core\src\utils\plugin_loader.impl.hpp (67) cv::plugin::impl::DynamicLib::libraryLoad load opencv_core_parallel_openmp452_64d.dll => FAILED
```

What do I have to do to get inference engine working correctly?
Thanks in advance for your answer

Comment: Have you tried installing one of those backends, like [oneTBB](https://github.com/oneapi-src/oneTBB/releases/tag/v2021.2.0)?

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost you need to install some pre-requisite for OpenVINO.

Then, you need to set it up properly in your system.

You can follow [this step by step guide](https://docs.openvinotoolkit.org/latest/openvino_docs_install_guides_installing_openvino_windows.html).

Answer (score 0):

To get the Inference Engine working in the OpenCV DNN module, you need to first install OpenVINO in your system. You can check out [this guide](https://www.samontab.com/web/2023/06/how-to-build-openvino-2023-0-in-ubuntu-22-04-2-lts-and-run-an-example/).

After that, you need to [compile OpenCV](https://www.samontab.com/web/2023/02/installing-opencv-4-7-0-in-ubuntu-22-04-lts/) with the cmake option `-DWITH_OPENVINO=ON` and its location with `-DOpenVINO_DIR=~/openvino-2023.0/build/install/runtime/cmake` or wherever you installed it. Make sure that the cmake output reports the correct version of OpenVINO you previously installed before starting to build OpenCV. It should say something like this:

```
--     OpenVINO:                    YES (2023.0.0)
```

After you build it, you will be able to use the DNN module in OpenCV as usual and OpenVINO will be the default backend. You can also set the backend you want to use by setting [setPreferableBackend](https://docs.opencv.org/4.7.0/db/d30/classcv_1_1dnn_1_1Net.html#a7f767df11386d39374db49cd8df8f59e) to either `DNN_BACKEND_INFERENCE_ENGINE` or `DNN_BACKEND_OPENCV`